# Xcode picks wrong version of header file with same name

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, frameworks, header-files

A similar question has been asked and answered [here](http://Two%20targets,%20two%20header%20files%20with%20the%20same%20name%20how%20to%20use%20each%20header%20for%20the%20right%20target?), however the solution provided does not solve my problem.

My Project has two targets: A Cocoa Framework (macOS) and a Cocoa Touch Framework (iOS).

The Frameworks share a lot of source files and headers, but there are files that are specific to each framework (due to platform differences).

In particular, both frameworks each have a class named `ViewController`.

On iOS, it is declared like this:

(`$(SRC_ROOT)`/Platforms/**iOS**/ViewController/ViewController.h:)

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController 
...
```

On the Mac, like this:

(`$(SRC_ROOT)`/Platforms/**macOS**/ViewController/ViewController.h:)

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface ViewController : NSViewController 
...
```

I also have **a third class**, `Manager`, that is common to both platforms.

It is just a subclass of `NSObject` and thus its header file only needs to import the platform-agnostic `<Foundation/Foundation.h>`.

But this class's methods interact with the aforementioned `ViewController`, so the implementation file imports that header:

(`$(SRC_ROOT)`/Common/Manager.m:)

```
#import "Manager.h"
#import "ViewController.h" // <-- THIS

@implementation Manager
...
```

**Now**, when I build the iOS target everything is fine.

But when I try to build the macOS target, the iOS version of ViewController.h gets somehow imported and I get the following error:

> Lexical or Preprocessor Issue - 'UIKit/UIKit.h' file not found

...pointing at the `#import` statement in Manager.m.

Some more information:

1. ViewController.h is a public header in both frameworks, and is included in the umbrella headers for both targets:

   ```
   #import <MyFramework/ViewController.h>
   ```
2. Each version of the header has target membership set to the appropriate target.
3. For both targets, **Header Search Paths** and **User Header Search Paths**is blank, and **Always Search User Paths** is NO.
4. I have tried to set **Header Search Paths** to each of the following values, to no avail:

   - `$(SRC_ROOT)/Platforms/macOS/`
   - `$(SRC_ROOT)/Platforms/macOS/**`
   - `./Platforms/macOS/`
   - `./Platforms/macOS/**`
5. I tried **deleting** the iOS version of the header temporarily, and the build **succeeded**. But after restoring the file and cleaning the build folder, it fails again.

**How can I get Xcode to "see" the right version of the header, on the Mac  target?**

---

**EDIT:** I tried the same path values from point (4) for "Framework Search Paths". Same error.

---

**UPDATE:**

If I set the build setting **Always Search User Paths** to **YES** (the default is NO), my framework builds. I can even build a sample Mac app that links to it and it runs. However, I get the warning:

> Warning: using 'ALWAYS_SEARCH_USER_PATHS = YES' while building targets
>   which define modules ('DEFINES_MODULE = YES') may fail. Please migrate
>   to using 'ALWAYS_SEARCH_USER_PATHS = NO'.

...but I read somewhere this would cause trouble down the line (can't find the post now).

---

**UPDATE 2:**

If, in addition,  I change the build setting **Defines Module** to **NO** (as suggested by the warning), both the framework and the app that embeds it build succesfully, and the framework's classes are available (i.e., instantiable) from the app's code.

However, I fear this whole "not defining a module" business is going to cause trouble when I attempt to use my framework from an app written in Swift...?

Comment: If I understand correctly, `ViewController` is in the framework, correct? You should double check to see that you are actually using the right framework for the Mac target. Also double check your Framework Search paths.

Comment: Yes, it is a file in the framework. I am compiling the frameworks themselves, not apps linking to them; I don't see why the Framework Search Paths would be relevant. Each version of the header is a member of the appropriate framework target (platform).

Comment: check your mac target Framework Search Paths to make sure it's not include iOS framework path. And add Your mac framework path here

Comment: `Framework Search Paths` is blank by default on both targets. I tried changing it to `$(SRC_ROOT)/Platforms/macOS/**`, to no avail.

Comment: With similar hesitation, currently working for me and I'm very thankful for your detailed post! Mysteries of Xcode..